# How to use remove_if with erase

Tags: c++, remove-if

I would like to know how to remove an object from a list base on a condition.

After researching, this is what I got, but it still doesn't work!

So I would like to know how to use `remove_if` with erase.

```
Class A
{
public:
    A(int x,int y);
    int x;
    int y;
};


int main()
{
    list<A> listA;

    A lista1(123,32);
    listA.push_back(lista1);
    A lista2(3123,1233);
    listA.push_back(lista2);
    A lista3(123,4123);
    listA.push_back(lista3);

    //HERE HOW TO REMOVE LIST if x = 123?
    listA.erase(remove_if(listA.begin(),listA.end(),/*REMOVE CRITERIA*/);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`std::list` has a `remove_if` member function:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/remove_if/

For your predicate you could either write a functor:

```
struct RemoveIfX
{
    RemoveIfX(int x) : m_x(x) {}

    bool operator() (const A& a)
    {
        return (a.x == m_x);
    }

    int m_x;
};

listA.remove_if(RemoveIfX(123));
```

Or use a lambda:

```
listA.remove_if([](const A& a) { return (a.x == 123); });
```

Comment: hi there, thanks for your reply! so are you saying i should overload my Class A operator()?

Comment: No, RemoveIfX is a standalone helper class. Lambdas are generally preferred these days as they are more concise. I gave both options in case you were using a compiler with no support for them.

Comment: I would like to know more about the lambda method (I tried it but got only compiler errors with g++ 4.4.1).

Comment: I think it might have only been added from 4.5 onwards. There might be some useful general information for you here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293608.aspx

Comment: @bleep this is awesome stuff. Unfortunately, it won't port to old versions of gcc (I'm writing code which is intended to be public).

Comment: The RemoveIfX version should work even with quite old versions of gcc.